# Split address into house#, streetname, zip5, zip4 in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I have address example:
123 Main street,
City
12345-8761
how can I split the above address into House# 123, Streetname: Main street, zip5-12345, zip4-8761
and I want to store these values in a variable and call those into XML request before I submit to service endpoint

Comment: Provide code, show what you've tried, show your desired input/output. SO isn't a script writing service

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way of achieving your goal is using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Example code:

```
def address = '123 Main street, City 12345-8761'

def numberAndStreet = address.split(',')[0].trim()
def cityAndZip = address.split(',')[1]

def houseNumber = (numberAndStreet =~ /(\d+)/)[0][1]
def street = numberAndStreet.replace(houseNumber, '').trim()

def zip = (cityAndZip =~ /(\d+-\d+)/)[0][1] 
def city = cityAndZip.replace(zip, '')

vars.put('houseNumber', houseNumber)
vars.put('street', street)
vars.put('zip', zip)
vars.put('city', city)
```

Demo:

[image]

You will be able to refer the extracted values referencing the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

- `${houseNumber}`
- `${street}`
- `${zip}`
- `${city}`

where required